# bootstrap 4 character set utf8, ñ no working

Tags: bootstrap, utf-8

bootstrap 4 character set utf8, ñ no working...

I need Latin characters like ñ to appear

Necesito que aparezcan la letra "Ñ"
Pero obtengo esto.
� �

Que etiqueta debo agregar o modificar.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>character UTF</title>
  </head>
  <body>


 <h1>  ñññññ</h1>
   
   
  </body>
</html>
```

---

No funciona....
He intentado de varias maneras y sigue sin funcionar pero he probado con 2 navegadores... Google chrome and Chromium edge

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No working google chrome and chromium edge

Comment: Traduce tu título al español por favor

Comment: Saludos. Prueba poniendo ` <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">.` donde actualmente tienes `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`; ahora bien; eso desde luego implicara que tu todo lo que allí se mostrara esta ya en codificación utf-8 para que se muestre correctamente.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: Miguelon, es importante realizar las preguntas en el idioma oficial del sitio, saludos-

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>character UTF</title>
  </head>
  <body>


 <h1>  ñññññ</h1>
   
   
  </body>
```

Proba ahora... el problema esta en el meta, aca la solución

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```